# Are non-static final variables useful in Java?

Tags: java

This question discusses the practices of non-static final variables.

My first impression is that non-static final variables are useless because final variables cannot be reassigned after initialization.

```
class Foo {
    public static final int BAR = 10;
}
```

That would mean all the objects created from type `Foo` would have `BAR = 10`.

When would it be useful, practical, or accepted to use non static, but final variables, like so?

```
class Foo {
    public final int BAR = 10;
}
```

So in what case does the latter become useful? Since it basically means the same thing.

Comment: If you set it in the ctor.

Comment: *“with the final modifier on a variable, nothing can change it after initialization, right?”* – In your example, yes.  However, be aware not to confuse `final` in Java with `const` in C++.  If it is not a primitive type but a class that carries state which can be altered by public methods, then that state can be changed even if the variable is declared `final`.

Comment: @JClassic [did so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25715922/1392132)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`final` in Java is not to be confused with `const` in C++.  Declaring a variable `final` means that it cannot be reassigned.  If the variable is a primitive type, this is fine.  If the variable is a reference type, declaring it `final` does not prevent it from mutating.

This is safe (as `int` is a primitive type) and commonly accepted:

```java
class Week {
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 7;
}

Week.NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 6;  // error: cannot reassign final variable
```

This is also safe.  While `java.lang.String` is not a primitive type, it is guaranteed to be immutable.  (Ie `String` has no method that changes its value and it must never get one or a quite fundamental language-level contract will be broken.)  I still find that many people dislike this use of public attributes and many style guides ban it.

```java
class Weekday {
    public final String name;

    public Weekday(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Weekday monday = new Weekday("Monday");
monday.name = "Tuesday";  // error: cannot reassign final variable
```

This is not safe:

```java
class Week {
    public static final String[] DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = {
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
      "Sunday",
    };
}

Week.DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = new String[6];  // error: cannot reassign final variable
Week.DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK[2] = "February";  // this is not prevented!
```

Using a `java.util.Collection` would not have made the last example much better. There are `Collection`s that amputate all mutating methods but the only thing this will buy us is a run-time error.  The compiler can't help here.

Comment: Thank you :) I've never dealt with c++ but I guess this scenario hasn't crossed my mind

Answer (score 6):

When that same animal has a field like this:

```
private final Animal mother;
```

Everyone only has one biological mother and there is no shared mom, meaning it is specific for each instance.

Making it `static` means that the value is shared amongst all instances. If this is what you want then it makes sense ofcourse.

Comment: What if you inline initialized the variable, so all of them had the same "mother"

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, but sure: if you start from the assumption that it will be the same value for every instance then you might as well indicate that by making it `static`.

Comment: Thanks that was my question.

Answer (score 2):

A common use case for this is lock objects.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
...
synchronized(lock) {...}
```

This pattern some times requires that the lock object belong to the instance and not to the class (`static`).

Answer (score 0):

If the field type is immutable, then it only makes sense if it's a value assigned by a constructor.

```
final class Point {
    final double x, y;
    Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

If the field's value is mutable, then it does make sense to have a `final` field initialized at its declaration site, because each instance will get its own reference.

```
final class ListWrapper<A> {
    final List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

But in the example you gave, no, it never makes sense to initialize a field as `public final int SIZE = 10;`.